# CMake installation

Tags: ios, cmake

I installed CMake (on ios), and it seemed like the installation was completed.

However, when I type

```
cmake -version
```

I get

```
-bash: cmake: command not found
```

Is there a need to set up CMake before using it?

Comment: How did you install it? Jailbroken phone?

Comment: It might help if you can clarify what you are doing. Which installation instructions are you following? Does "CMake (on ios)" mean using cmake to build an executable which can run on iOS or are you trying to actually run the cmake tool on a (presumably jailbroken) iOS device? What do you know about the state of the install now; can you find the `cmake` binary, is that in a location on your PATH?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're talking about OS X, not iOS: CMake is installed, but not in the PATH in your shell. You can add it via something like:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Appications/CMake.app/Contents/bin
```

Then the cmake command will work on the command line.

You can edit the file ~/.bashrc to set your PATH this way every time you open the command line, instead of needing to do it manually each time.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)

Answer (score 1):

you can open CMake with GUI in Launchpad, and click the "tools" - > "How to Install For Command Line Use" menu, you'll find ways to solve it

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer pointing to /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin is correct but you can go one step further.

If you run

```
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake-gui --install
```

Then it will link the executables into /usr/local/bin.